# If $||f_n||_{L^2}\leq 1$, then $\frac{f_n}{n}\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have a question regarding a comment in Exercise 27 in Chapter 6 of Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis. He says that if $\big\{f_n\big\} \subset L^2(X,d\mu)$ with $||f_n||_{L^2}\leq 1$, then $f_n(x)/n \rightarrow 0$ for a.e. x. Here we are considering a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$. Intuitively, I would think we prove this by
$$\Big|\Big|\frac{f_n}{n}\Big|\Big|_{L^2} = \Big( \int_X \Big|\frac{f_n(x)}{n}\Big|^2 d\mu(x) \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{|n|}\Big(\int_X |f_n(x)|^2d\mu(x) \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \frac{1}{|n|}$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_n}{n} = 0$$
However, this can't be true because the same proof could be used to show that the result holds in the case where we consider the $L^1$ norm, which is false. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $k>0$, note that
$$ \mu(\lvert f_n\rvert/n>1/k) \leq \frac{\lVert f_n/n \rVert_2^2}{(1/k)^2} \leq \frac{k^2}{n^2} $$
by Markov's inequality. This way,
$$ \mu(\lvert f_n\rvert/n > 1/k \text{ for infinitely many }n)=0 $$
thanks to Borel-Cantelli. (Note that this uses that $\sum 1/n^2<\infty$, which is the key difference of using $L^2$ instead of $L^1$.) At last, we get that
$$ \mu\left(x : \exists k, \lvert f_n\rvert/n>1/k \text{ for infinitely many }n \right)=0 $$
by countable additivity. You can easily check that the complement consists of points $x$ such that for all $k$, there exists some $n_0$ such that $\lvert f_n(x)/n\rvert < 1/k$ for $n \geq n_0$, hence $f_n(x)/n \to 0$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you used countable additivity to say that $\mu (x:\exists k,|f_n|/n>1/k \text{ for infinitely many n}) =0$?

Comment: Also, is that the correct statement of Markov's inequality? The one I am familiar with would not have the squares.

Comment: For the first question, note that the "exists some $k$" can be expressed as a union, and that allows us to use countable (sub)additivity.

Comment: The second one also works for squares; for instance, by writting
$$ \mu(|f|>\alpha) = \mu(|f|^2>\alpha^2) \leq (\int |f|^2)/\alpha^2 $$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense about Markov's inequality. Couldn't we conclude directly from $\mu (|f_n|/n>1/k\text{ for infinitely many n}) =0$ that for almost every $x$, $|f_n(x)|/n>1/k$ for finitely many $n$, and hence there exists some $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)/n|<1/k$ for all $n\geq n_0$?

Comment: What you said is correct, but for a fixed $k$. Then we would want to say that it holds "for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$", and then you are essentially using that a countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero, which is equivalent to what I wrote.